# Using Resharper inspectcode for Xamarin projects

Tags: xamarin, resharper

I am developing xamarin project and want to analyze it with jetbrains-commandline-tools (inspectcode). But, I have C# compiler errors - Cannot resolve symbol '...'. How to use inspectcode for xamarin projects?

Comment: Does that same error occur when you open and build the solution with Visual Studio or Xamarin Studio?

Comment: No. There is no error. It compiles and runs fine.